# How do I change/set this Local variable into a global one

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

```
def SelectedCarFunction(event=None):
    a = Var2.get()
    b = Var3.get()
    c = Var4.get()  
    if Model == "a" and Colour == "b" and Wheels == "c":
        VarSC = (Three_Series[0])
        print(VarSC)
```

When I print VarSC from the function it gives me the value I want

```
VarSC = StringVar()

print(VarSC)
```

But when I print it outside the function, within my code, it prints "PY_VAR9"

Comment: Please be a little specific. You are saying that you want to print VarSC outside the method ?

Comment: Yes I want to use VarSC outside the method

Answer (score 1):

You should return the value of VarSC from the function and print it outside.

```
def SelectedCarFunction(event=None):
    a = Var2.get()
    b = Var3.get()
    c = Var4.get()  
    if Model == "a" and Colour == "b" and Wheels == "c":
        VarSC = (Three_Series[0])
        return VarSC

print(SelectedCarFunction())
```

Comment: I did that and it prints out None

Comment: I want VarSC to become a variable outside the method

Comment: It prints out now

Comment: write VarSC = SelectedCarFunction() rather than print(SelectedCarFunction()). Dont forget to mark it answered if your problem is fixed.